# Upgrade Mongoose to version 5

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm currently using Mongoose version 4.4.5 for my MEAN stack application.  I need to update Mongoose to version 5 or higher to resolve an issue where Mongoose versions prior to 5.0 are incorrectly matched for MongoDB 3.6. MongoDB 3.6 changed the aggregate API from "cursor optional" to "cursor only", and older mongoose versions break this by trying to invoke a deprecated way to ask for an array in response.  Since I'm using MongoDB version 4.0.2, this version of MongoDB also makes the cursor option a requirement for the aggregate API.

I'm unable to find specific guidance on how to upgrade Mongoose to version 5.0 using npm.  I could use

```
npm update mongoose@5.0.0
```

but need to specific guidance on what else I need to do to make sure the new mongoose version correctly connects to MongoDB, that all the schemas and models defined for my current mongoose version transition seamlessly to the new mongoose.

Can someone please provide this guidance?  I've never done this before and can't find specific steps anywhere online.

Comment: I couldn't find this linked in the current Mongoose documentation, but the GitHub repo does have a helpful [Guide to Migrating to Mongoose 5](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/85909e1fae6bf8a1526a5207216826c396df61de/migrating_to_5.md).

Comment: Missing a link to the migration guide in the Mongoose 5 documentation was an oversight. The above guide is now published at: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_5.html.